# modal popup server side handling

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I try to use the ajax modal popup but when i click the target button nothing is happen !!

```
protected void ibtn_login_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
                    .........
                    pnl_email.Visible = true;
                    this.mod_email.Show();
                    .........

        }
```

---

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_email" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <table border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="MainTable">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <label>
                        UserMail<font color="red"> *</font></label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_email" runat="server" Width="350px" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                        ControlToValidate="txt_email" ValidationGroup="E">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_email"
                        ErrorMessage="Invalid mail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                        ValidationGroup="E">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_confirmMail" runat="server" Text="Confirm Mail" OnClick="btn_confirmMail_Click"
                        ValidationGroup="E" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mod_email" runat="server" TargetControlID="ibtn_login" 
        PopupControlID="pnl_email" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="true"
        OkControlID="btn_confirmMail">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

---

I get the following error from IE :

> SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
>   ScriptResource.axd?d=92AV6VxPb6EpSOraO2TfCghg2URfn_e1UnUMJeJSBpUklUTQUPbjulsV4_SUVHYavVKrhWStNKamtzKpd-i0CMF0IZIaiu5Rsqsi2-YgiWOQswz5wtr2VOzzJrpNOMeTHlqd4KNSoOxi2-yulEg6OaXbmIU1&t=ffffffff9b7d03cf,
>   line 1262 character 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod_email.show()`I think is what you are looking for

Also, try

either wrapping an update panel within the asp:Panel or placing the contents within the updatepanel
`<asp:Panel ID="pnl_email" runat="server" Visible="false">`

`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">`

`<ContentTemplate>`

`<table border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="MainTable">`

`...`

`</table>`

`</ContentTemplate>`

`</asp:UpdatePanel>`

`</asp:Panel>`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have **scriptmanager**  on your page:

```
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:scriptmanager>
```

Comment: I have a script manager . and if i don't ,the error will appear